# Form to Add an User and Validate name/email in AD

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

In my page, I need and form to add Users in an request.
I need validate this Name or Email that was entered, in Activity Directory.
Anybody have an form (ASPX, HTML, Javascript) that insert Users and C# to validate this value in AD?

Today, it's what I have but visualy it's ugly and don't validates what was entered.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserAdd" runat="server" Height="17px" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddUser" class="btn" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Add User" OnClick="btnSendUser_OnClick" />
    <br />
    <table id="tblUsers" CssClass="table table-bordered">
        <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    </table>


protected void btnSendUser_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblUser.Visible = true;
    lblUser.Text = txtUserAdd.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though personally I have never worked with Active Directories, so I am going to assume that "active directories" are just like databases. There is information on MSDN [Active Directory Authentication from ASP .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). Currently I have 3 ways you can check for authentication in your ASP.net app.

**1. Using regular expression**

```
public class Test_Validation
{
  public bool Test_User(string username)
  {
  // Setup your username pattern
    const string pattern = @"^[a-z0-9_-]{3,15}$"/*NICE SAMPLE Username REGEX!*/;
    // check if the pattern matches
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(/*The string to check the pattern on*/username, /* the regular expression pattern */pattern, /* a flag for REGEX */ System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("  (match for '{0}' found)", pattern);
    }
    else
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Sorry, no match found");
    }
  }
}
```

**1+ Using if/else statements and parsing the string, this seems very verbose and unnecessary explanation.**

**2. Using jQuery validation.** You can read up on jQuery validation on this site: [An Example of Using the jQuery Validation Plug-in](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213138/An-Example-to-Use-jQuery-Validation-Plugin)

**3. Use Data-Annotation attributes**
Here is a nice article on using Data-Annotation: [Using Attributes to Define Validation Rule Sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649167.aspx)

Sorry there is not many code example listed, just ask me and I will be more than happy to elaborate more on what type of validation you want to go forward and use, (I would personally go with the last option)

Answer (score 0):

custom validator server side 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5db6z8k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

for AD, use System.DirectoryServices, I use DirectorySearcher